# 301 http response on uploading file from android AndroidAsyncHttp to django

Tags: android, django, android-async-http

can someone help me . tried to upload file from android using AndroidAsyncHttp api to django , but getting http exception "pemanently moved exception" 301 . this process worked locally but when uploading site to production it didnt work and the request method is redirected to the same url

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working, For any one who will face the problem later . This is what i did.

The url to which post request was submitted included the www.
as  : http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/setPost/

also the

on the django setting file  i did the following to the allowed-host
ALLOWED-HOST=["*"]

i also exempted the csrftoken by ; @exempt_csrf